# Apache: "Virtualhost not allowed here" error when using If condition

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a condition inside `httpd.conf` that looks like this:

```
<If "-f '/some/path/to/existing/file'">
   <VirtualHost _default:$port1>
     ServerName example.com

     ...config1...
   </VirtualHost>
</If>
</Else>
   <VirtualHost _default:$port1>
     ServerName example.com

     ...config2...
   </VirtualHost
</Else>
```

However, it's giving me a syntax error AH00526 that says "VirtualHost not allowed here". If I comment out the "If Else" condition, and put a VirtualHost outside the block, it works.

How could I fix this while keeping the condition?

Comment: I think virtualhosts are not allowed inside If Statements.

Comment: Just out of interest, what are you trying to achieve? Multiple servers with the same config, but it changes depending on which files are there?

Comment: yes, I have some rails apps that are authenticated with OIDC (https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) and some authenticated by another method. Only one app runs at a time, but all the apps share the same apache conf. All the apps use the same server name and port. SSLEngine On.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following. Instead of using `If` directives (which are really intended for checking request parameter, you could try using the [IfFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#Iffile) directive.

`IfFile` checks if a file exists at startup. It has no else option, so you will need to make sure your file checks are exclusive for each server.

Comment: This requires apache version 2.4.34 and later. It will take me some time to upgrade and try it out.

Comment: @konyak Also, as you accepted the answer, you could also award them the bounty.

Comment: I just did, thanks. Something was wrong in the browser the first time I tried to award it.